# Finding the minimum of some function

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratics, quadratic-forms

Suppose $x,y,z$ are real numbers satisfying,
$$
x+y+z=0, \frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{y^2}{b}+\frac{z^2}{c}=1
$$
for some numbers $0<a,b,c$ and $a+b+c=1$.
I am trying to minimize the following quantity:
$$
xyA+yzB+xzC,
$$
for some numbers $A>0,B>0,C>0$.

When there is no constraint on the sum that $x+y+z=0$, I am able to deal it with matrix theory, that is, with some manipulation, I am going to find the minimum of eigenvalue of a particular matrix. However, adding this constraint, I have no good ways to solve it so far.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried Lagrange multiplier method?

Comment: Sure, but it became kind of messy. So I am trying to see if there are other ways that work. Thank you.